# Is there a name for the fallacy of not doing something because something bad happens anyway?

Tags: fallacies

The idea goes something like this: We can't do something good to try to stop something bad because something else bad, that is independent of the first, still might happen. (Key word still).

Is there a name for this? 
Example:
We can't teach people how to be safe in the city at night so they won't get robbed because then they just get robbed by their family or friends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be "perfect solution fallacy" aka "nirvana fallacy", meaning that any solution but a perfect one must be rejected. In this case, rejecting any course of action that doesn't prevent *all* robberies.

Comment: Depending on the argument that wouldn't be a fallacy but a bias.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to appear in any lists of common fallacies, although I would suggest terming it the **fatalistic fallacy**.  In general, it would be a claim that all outcomes are the same, therefore all progressions to that outcome are equivalent, so it might be considered a special case of the [false equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_equivalence) fallacy.

Answer (score 0):

Fallacy of greater privation.

“We’re all dead anyway”